# Making simple election results map using CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I'm creating a simple map in Cartodb to show the results of a local school referendum vote.

https://tmeyer1969.cartodb.com/viz/9a87c650-e8e2-11e5-8f7f-0e31c9be1b51/public_map

I think I've got the basics figured out in just one day but I'm hoping to shade each precinct in a gradient based on ranges of the margin of victory (positive if 'yes' wins, negative if 'no' wins). For example, > 10% would get the greenest green, 7.5-9.99% slightly lighter, 5.0-7.49 slightly lighter, < 0% pale red, < -10% dark red, etc .. Pretty much like conditional formatting in excel. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to create a choropleth map which is easy to do.  I hope the screenshot below helps:
[image]

Comment: thanks ! Reversing/fiddling with the colors and order was simple too.